# Offset/Resize previously defined range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to clear everything (including images) from the cells on sheets 4 to 9 and then also 12 and 13. I have the following code, but it's clearing the contents from sheets 3-9 and 12-15 and I have no idea why.

Any thoughts?

```
Sub ClearContents()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 4 To 9 And 12 And 13
Sheets(i).Cells.Clear
Sheets(i).Pictures.Delete

Next i
```

Comment: I would have thought that it should have only acted on sheets 4 to 8 (because `9 And 12 And 13` equals `8`).

Comment: In case anyone doesn't get that point, @YowE3K's is referring to the bitwise AND of those three numbers, which would mean the error arose due to mistaken operator precedence. It was my first thought too...

Comment: @YowE3K From what I gathered by skimming, it might be going according to the current order in the UI, and not the sheet name numeric suffixes, which become arbitrary after having their initial sequence number assigned? Currently missing numbers from that sequence might account for the difference in totals?

Comment: @GlennSlayden - I just saw the OP's comment to an answer saying their sheets go "Sheet 1, Sheet10, Sheet11, Sheet12, Sheet13, Sheet14, Sheet15, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5, Sheet6, Sheet7,Sheet8, Sheet9", so I would expect the code to act on "Sheet12, Sheet13, Sheet14, Sheet15, Sheet2".  Now that includes Sheet2 (which isn't mentioned in the question) and excludes "Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5, Sheet6, Sheet7,Sheet8, Sheet9" (which are mentioned as being affected).  Sigh - I think I am just going to have to accept that the question and reality are not associated in any way.

Comment: @YowE3K I don't work with Excel very often, but I have a vague recollection of battling with an issue in this area probably decades ago. Glad to see it's still doing well.

Comment: @GlennSlayden - LOL - It gets even more confusing when you include the sheet codenames.  If you start off with a single sheet called "Sheet1", insert another sheet called "Sheet2", open the VBA IDE, go back to Excel and create a sheet called "Sheet3" (while on "Sheet2") then:...  the sheet called "Sheet1" can be referenced as `Sheet2` or `Sheets("Sheet1")` or `Sheets(3)`, "Sheet2" can be referenced as `Sheet1` or `Sheets("Sheet2")` or `Sheets(2)`, and "Sheet3" can be referenced as `Sheet3` or `Sheets("Sheet3")` or `Sheets(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearContents()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim PicObj As Object

    ' loop through all worksheets in your workbook
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case Sht.Index
            Case 4 To 9, 12, 13
                Sht.Cells.Clear

                ' loop through all shapes in your worksheet and delete them all
                For Each PicObj In Sht.Shapes
                    PicObj.Delete
                Next PicObj

            Case Else '<-- for future cases, if you'll need
                'do nothing
        End Select
    Next Sht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Edited to use sheet names instead of their index

you could use the `Sheets(array)` *flavour* of `Sheets` collection:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearContents()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet12", "Sheet13")) ' loop through wanted worksheets
        ws.Cells.Clear
        ws.Pictures.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a really nice and short version so hopefully I can get it to work. I tried it but right now it's still clearing the same sheets as before. I don't know if maybe it could be picking up on the order of my sheets in terms of how they're arranged in my workbook? From right to left they go: Sheet 1, Sheet10, Sheet11, Sheet12, Sheet13, Sheet14, Sheet15, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5, Sheet6, Sheet7,Sheet8, Sheet9

Comment: I tried it again and from what I can tell it is using the order of the worksheets rather than the actual worksheet number.

Comment: In your code you used Sheets(i) with i being a number so that's what I used also. And that uses the sheets "order". If you must use their names then use  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet12", "Sheet13"))

Comment: @user7431724 - it might be an idea to update the question to say things like "Sheet4, Sheet5, Sheet6, Sheet7, Sheet8, and Sheet9" instead of "sheets 4 to 9" - the two are completely different.

Comment: @user7431724, did you get through it?